# Add total label to tree footer odoo 12

Tags: treeview, odoo-12

I need to add a Total label on the last row from a tree, the last row is for sum values, how can I edit a tree footer?

*view.xml*

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='field_list']/tree/field[@name='name']" position="after">
  <field name="field1" sum="Total Field 1"/>
  <field name="field2" sum="Total Field 2"/>
  <field name="field3" sum="Total Field 3"/>
</xpath>
```

*screenshot*

[image]

Is there a way to edit the tree footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list footer is used to show aggregates (`sum`, `avg`), it is rendered in [_renderFooter](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js#L517)  of the `ListRenderer`.

***The method docstring:***

```
/**
     * Render the footer.  It is a <tfoot> with a single row, containing all
     * aggregates, if applicable.
     *
     * @private
     * @returns {jQueryElement} a <tfoot> element
     */
```

The method that computes aggregates will check for the field type, the computation will be ignored if the field type is not one of the following `integer`, `float` or `monetary`.

You can alter the `_renderFooter` to be able to provide a static text to display in the footer using a field attribute.

***Example:***

```js
var ListRenderer = require("web.ListRenderer");
ListRenderer.include({
        _renderFooter: function () {
            var res = this._super();
            _.each(this.columns, function (column) {
               if(!('aggregate' in column) && column.attrs.text) {
                   res.find('.'+column.attrs.name).text(column.attrs.text);
               }
            });
            return res;
        },
});
```

To add the above code, check the [Assets Management](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#assets-management) documentation.

To display the text in the footer of the corresponding column, set the `text` attribute in the field tag ( if the field contain an aggregate, the text will be ignored).

```
<field name="total" text="Total"/>
```